# Python Flask not deleting correct id from SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an HTML table which pulls data from an SQLAlchemy database.

In this table, for each row, I have a `Delete` button, which should delete that row and database entry when I click on it.

The issue I have, is that if I try to delete any row in this table, it deletes only the first row (see image below) and the associated data in the database.

The row and the data I wanted deleted remain unchanged (the 3rd row in the image below).

[image]

If I click `Delete` on the first row in the table, it works without issues.

The `Update` button works as indented (updating the correct entry)

This is the database model I have:

```
class ActualPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'actualpost'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title_actual = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='actual')
    category_actual = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default=None)
    actual_amount_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    actual_amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ActualPost('{self.title_actual}, '{self.category_actual}'\
        , '{self.actual_amount_name}', '{self.actual_amount}'\
        , '{self.date_posted}', '{self.comments}')"
```

Here are my routes (Update and Delete)

```
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update_actual", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update_actual_post(post_id):
    post = ActualPost.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if post.actual_author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    form = PostActualForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title_actual = form.title_actual.data
        post.category_actual = form.category_actual.data
        post.actual_amount_name = form.actual_amount_name.data.name
        post.actual_amount = form.actual_amount.data
        post.comments = form.comments.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.actual', post_id=post.id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.title_actual.data = post.title_actual
        form.category_actual.data= post.category_actual
        form.actual_amount_name.data = post.actual_amount_name
        form.actual_amount.data = post.actual_amount
        form.comments.data = post.comments
    return render_template('create_actual_post.html', title='Update Actual',
                           form=form, legend='Update Actual')


@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>/delete_actual", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_actual_post(post_id):
    post = ActualPost.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if post.actual_author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your post has been deleted!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('main.actual', post_id=post.id))
```

This is the HTML code I use for the Delete button:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <form action="{{ url_for('posts.delete_actual_post', post_id = post.id) }}" method="post">
     <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you are passing the correct `post_id` to the `get_or_404()` method by printing to console?

Comment: Also in your chrome/firefox developer tools, make sure you check that form's action property and ensure that its correct in the case of that delete button.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I have investigated further, and it seems that the `modal` I have in my html is the culprit. I have it placed in a `for` loop and it is not getting the ID correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code to delete particular row by id. You can co-relate it with your code

SQL-alchemy Modal :

```
class Componants(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'componants'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cmp_options = db.Column(db.Text, default=None)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)


def __init__(self , cmp_options ):
    self.cmp_options = cmp_options 
    self.created_at = datetime.now()
    self.updated_at = datetime.now()

def __repr__(self):
    return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

Controller :

```
@componants_blueprint.route('/delete_component/<component_id>')
@login_required
def delete_component(component_id):
    component = Componants.query.filter_by(id=component_id).first_or_404()
    db.session.delete(component)
    db.session.commit() 
    return True
```

View:

```
              <tbody>
                {% for item in all_components %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.cmp_options }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.created_at }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center"> 
                    <a href="{{ url_for('componants.delete_component', component_id=item.id) }}" title="Delete" class="far fa-trash-alt"></a>
                  </td>    
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above did not help me.
But the comments in this post did help me.

In short: the problem is inside the HTML tags. I used a 'modal' from the Bootstrap.

The comments in this page suggested to inspect the page elements.

> Also in your chrome/firefox developer tools, make sure you check that form's action property and ensure that its correct in the case of that delete button. –
> Prahlad Yeri
> Jun 10, 2018 at 23:48

The inspection showed that each row in the table did create 'some' unique features such as the name of the item I like to delete. However, during 'inspect' I clicked on my delete button. This showed that the action was stuck in the first line of the table. It did not jump to the line where I clicked 'delete'.

What is inside the HTML generating the issue? Is it the row or is it the modal?

I noticed that the html tag for the modal 'id' was the same for all rows in my table. Question: shouldn't it be unique for each row? I guess, yes.

So, I added the jinja tag to my ID. Would it work? Yes, for me it did...

```
{% block table %}
<table id="data" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Latitude</th>
          <th scope="col">Longitude</th>
          <th scope="col">Jars</th>
          <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for map in maps %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ map.map_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ map.latitude }}</td>
          <td>{{ map.longitude }}</td>
          <td><span style="white-space: pre-line">{% for jar in map.jar_id %}
                                                        {{ jar.jar_name }}
                                                    {% endfor %}
                </span>
            </td>
          <td><!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#{{map.map_name}}Modal">
                    Delete
                </button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="{{map.map_name}}Modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="{{map.map_name}}ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="{{map.map_name}}ModalLabel">Are you sure?</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Are you sure to delete the item : {{ map.map_name }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href="{{ url_for('map._map_name_delete', map_name=map.map_name) }}" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1" role="button">Yes</a>
                                <a href="{{ url_for('map.table_maps')}}" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1" role="button">No</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```